# How to assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable while preserving the new line characters

Tags: bash, makefile

I'd like to assign the output of a command to a Makefile variable, but the constraint is that I need to preserve the new line characters.

The value is a private key, hence the following code will result in a malformed key:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

APP_NAME?=foo

ifdef CI
    export DEPS_PRIVATE_KEY=$(shell echo $(CI_BASE64_PRIVATE_KEY) | base64 -d)
endif

build:
    @docker build --no-cache --build-arg DEPS_PRIVATE_KEY -t $(APP_NAME) .
.PHONY: build
```

I realize that I can set the value in bash and then call `make build` like so:

```
DEPS_PRIVATE_KEY="$(echo $CI_BASE64_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 -d)" make build
```

but I was wondering if it's possible to encapsulate this logic in the `Makefile`.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is no, there's no way to preserve newlines in the output of the `shell` function.  You will have to do something different.  One option is to write the output to a file, then use the `file` function (if you have a new-enough GNU make) to read it back into a variable.  The other (better) option is to follow Renaud's suggestion below.

Comment: Just from the title I knew this was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MadScientist makes sense, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Beta good call, I think it was a bit of a tunnel-visioned question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a make variable as an intermediate for a shell environment variable -- especially when the values are multi-line strings -- is probably uselessly complex. The simplest is thus probably to add the environment variable definition to your recipe:

```
$ cat Makefile
build:
    @export TXT="$$(echo "$$(B64)" | base64 -d)"; \
    printenv TXT
$ make B64="$(printf 'a\nb\n' | base64)"
export TXT="$(echo "YQpiCg==" | base64 -d)"; \
printenv TXT
a
b
```